# How do I get consistent behavior with matchadd color column?

Tags: highlight, colorcolumn

After watching Damian Conway's [talk](http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/10/more-instantly-better-vim.html), I added the following two lines to my `.vimrc`.

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=magenta
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v', 100)
```

My objective is to get the 81st column to be highlighted whenever a line goes beyond 80 characters. Unfortunately, if I open a new file and type `80i-`, then I get highlighting on the 81st column even though there is no character there.

If I manually delete the 80th character and type it again, I sometimes get highlighting on the 81st column and sometimes don't. When I have 80 characters, I'd prefer not to have the 81st column highlighted.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

The solution I'm using nowadays is:

```
matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v\s*\zs\S', 100)
```

That version highlights the first non-space character after column 80, which I find more useful.

Answer (score 4):

After digging around a bit on the internet, I found [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines) which achieves a similar effect but is more specific in the match.

The fix is to add a `.` after the `v`.

```
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v.', 100)
```