# How to execute a function when a diff closes

Tags: autocmd, vimdiff

I have a setting [(namely highlight the 81st character on the line)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/how-do-i-get-consistent-behavior-with-matchadd-color-column/10712#10712) that I would like to turn off when there is a diff. This is easy enough as a search through the autocmds results in:

> |FilterWritePre|  starting to write a file for a filter command or diff
>
> |FilterWritePost| after writing a file for a filter command or diff

So I end up with:

```
" Highlight the 81st character on the line if it's not the quickfix.
autocmd BufReadPost * if (&filetype != 'qf') |
                    \    let b:ColorColumnID = matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v.') |
                    \ endif

" When diffing take out the coloring because it looks like diff highlighting.
autocmd FilterWritePost * if (&diff && exists('b:ColorColumnID')) |
                        \    call matchdelete(b:ColorColumnID) |
                        \ endif
```

However, I would also like to turn the setting back on when I leave diff mode. As far as I can tell, there's no autocmd to detect this, and I can't think of any other robust ways to do it. Obviously I could check `&diff` on every cursor move or something like that, but I'm hoping for something a little less hacky. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it would work, because it depends on how you toggle the diff mode in a window, but if you use the `:set` command, maybe you could try to use the `OptionSet` event. With this event, the pattern is matched again the full name of an option, and Vim should populate the internal variables `v:option_old` and `v:option_new` with the old and new values of the option. Maybe something like this would be a start: `autocmd OptionSet diff if v:option_new ==# 'diff' | {disable custom highlighting} | else | {enable custom highlighting} | endif`.

Comment: Also, not sure, but I think the highlighting created by `matchadd()` is local to the window, not to the buffer, so maybe `w:` would be better than `b:` for the scope of the `ColorColumnID` variable.