# How to make the 81st column stand out in Lua?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

Like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10715/38417) for Vim, I'm trying to convert (with no success):

```
matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v\s*\zs\S', 100)
```

from vimscript to a Lua `autocmd`:

```lua
autocmd({'BufRead'}, {
    pattern = "*",
    callback = function ()
       vim.fn.matchadd('ColorColumn', '\\%81v\\s*\\zs\\S')
    end
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the colorcolumn option?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sure! `wo.colorcolumn = "80"` but show column always not only on characters >=81. This autocmd should replace the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```lua
autocmd({'BufRead'}, {
    pattern = "*",
    callback = function ()
       vim.fn.matchadd('ColorColumn', '\\%81v\\s*\\zs\\S', 100)
    end
})
```

Optional verify that the `ColorColumn` is defined:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "CursorColumn", { ctermbg = 0 })
```

Comment: Thanks, at the end `100` is missing

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)